# Uk visit family visa refused from france

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, bangladeshi-citizens

[image]
[image]

This is my 2nd time they refused my visa.

1st application was refused just because i didnt had enough income

But now  my income is much better than before since i joined my new job

And They didnt ask for the sponsor paper last time from my uncle who im going to visit in uk so i thought i do not need it

Now they are saying i didnt provide sponsorship

Will i get the visa if i reapply with sponsorship

Need help please?

Comment: We can't say for sure whether you'll get the visa if you do this or that. Personally I believe it wouldn't help, you should also address the nationality question and the financial aspects of the refusal, i.e. that you can afford a trip that would cost approximately one month's salary.

Comment: Im a bangladesi passport holder but have a residance card in france 4 years of valitidy

Comment: With two visa refusals, you would be wise not to reapply at this time. Your reasons for visiting and your finances were not very strong, and may have suggested that you would not leave the UK at all. A third refusals would make it very difficult for you to obtain a visa, and could result in a ban.

Comment: I would like to know should i reapply immediately with bank statement I've enough fund in my current account I didn't gave it cause I showed them the last 7 months  payslip

Comment: 1st refusul was 8 months ago ..

Comment: *If* you decide to reapply, you *must* address *all* of the issues raised in your previous refusals. Your nationality. Your finances (bank statements), which show that you can actually afford this trip. A sponsorship letter, with evidence of your sponsor's immigration status in the UK. Your lack of clarity on exactly how many days you're planning to spend in the UK. You need to read *and understand* the guidance at the link that you've been given in the refusal notice which explains the kinds of documentation which would be necessary for your application to succeed.

Comment: A national means that you have citizenship. They want to see how much you're spending and saving each month. Will the person you're visiting provide any housing, food, or money? Then you must document that too not just state it, etc.

Comment: Yes they will provide food and living buy I will provide the money for travelling

Comment: If, while reading the rules & guidance at those links, you find there's something you don't fully understand, come back here and ask a question about that specific thing so that e can try to help.

Comment: Can you tell me...soon im going a buy a car in france ive passed my drivinh its been a month will it make any difference if i show them car detalis n driving

Comment: Does owning a car and having permission to drive it, affect any of the issues raised in the refusal? If not, it will not make a difference.

Comment: I meant i dnt have a car in france yet but soon i will buy one and if i show it to them will it make any stronger my  future visaapplication because they think im not seeking a genuine visit visa and also they think my links in france is very low when it is not ive a full time work n i live on my own in a rent appartment ...

Comment: @Wadud Rahman It’s highly unlikely proving car ownership would have any effect on a visa decision. As others have said, you should concentrate on addressing the reasons for the refusals, particularly a credible reason for the visit (eg invitation from your uncle, his bank statements if he’s providing financial support, evidence he can host you in his property if it’s rented), your ties to France (eg job, savings,rental agreement), your ability to pay for the trip (bank statements showing receipt of your salary and a surplus of income over expenditure, savings).

Comment: Thanks so how long it would be nice to make a new visa application and for the bank statement i want to know ive made a loan frm my bank in france for a buying a car recetly will it make any possible problem im sorry but im really stress about the refusal n im scared if they ban me

Comment: @Wadud Rahman In theory, having a bank loan approved is a good thing because it shows you have a positive credit history. It’s a bad thing if it looks as if you’ve obtained the loan to try to make your financial situation look better for your visa application. It would probably be a good idea to be able to provide statements showing the bank loan monies being paid out (to buy the car) and several months-worth (minimum of 3, for example) of repayments. The best advice is not to reapply unless you are confident that your application is strong and supported by all relevant evidence.

Comment: Thanks once again and can you tell me what is the difference between geneal visit visa and family visit visa? Coz i think my friend same situation as me he had his visa few months ago he applied for general visit visa where he didnt needed any sponsorship he just put his cousin sister name n adress in uk where he will be staying...

Comment: @Wadud Rahman All this information is available on the UK gov website, you really need to read and understand if you intend to reapply. To summarise, a Family Visa allows the holder to live with a family member (spouse or partner, child or parent) in the UK for more than 6 months https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa A Standard Visit Visa is for less than 6 months, which is what you require given the purpose and intended duration of your trip. The ECO wants to see an invitation from your uncle & proof of his immigration status in the UK, similarities with your friend’s application are irrelevant.

Comment: For the next application should i book and pay the travel ticket to show them i am able to do so

Answer (score 1):

There’s no quick fix for this, and with two successive refusals you do not want to risk a third. Reading the refusal letters it seems that you do not understand how to put together a coherent application and as a result you failed to meet and/or prove pretty much every criteria. First off, read the application guidance https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa , the supporting documents guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf and the Visit Guidance https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visit-guidance Next, make a list of all the supporting documents that are relevant to your circumstances and of all the refusal reasons given by the ECO, then identify how/if you can address them so that you can provide evidence with your application that supports all the statements you make in it. Use the UKVI Document Checklist from your previous applications to help you.